# Convert a number of zip file to rar?

Tags: macos, compression

Any suggestion of how to convert tens of `zip` files to `rar` format? App or command line tool are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you could do is making a little batch file that would use [RAR](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11159/rar/), a shareware command line utility for mac (I did not find any free rar command line utility, but RAR is available as a trial).

### Installing rar command

To install RAR into your terminal, simply copy `rar` and `unrar` into your `bin` folder.

To get access to the `bin` directory, open Terminal.app and type

```
open ­/bin
```

The Windows version of RAR allows to "convert" `zip` archive into `rar` archive in tools, but the mac version doesn't seem to have this feature. The solution would be to unzip each of the files into separate folders and then to RAR content of those folders right away.

### The Solution

```
#!/bin/bash
# shell script that will convert zip files into rar files
# Require RAR for Mac os x to be placed in bin folder

# Working directory, use ~ for home folder shortcut :)
WorkingDirectory=~/test

# Temp directory that will be used for zip files manipulation
# Will prevent loop from raring other folders ;)
TempDirectory="${WorkingDirectory}"/zipToRarTemp

# Target Directory is where you want the rar files to go after the process
TargetDirectory="${WorkingDirectory}"

# Let's create the directories
mkdir "${TempDirectory}"
mkdir "${TargetDirectory}"

# Will loop into WorkingDirectory and unzip each .zip files
for file in "${WorkingDirectory}"/*.zip
do
    # Get file name
    # See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash
    # 1st answer
    filename=$(basename "$file")
    extension="${filename##*.}"
    filename="${filename%.*}"

    # Temp folder in the loop
    tempFolderToRar="${TempDirectory}"/"${filename}"

    # Create folders to rar later
    mkdir "${tempFolderToRar}"

    # unzip -d folder/extract/to fileToExtract.zip
    unzip -d "${TempDirectory}"/"${filename}" "${file}"

    # rar all the files in tempFolderToRar into the target
    rar a "${TargetDirectory}"/"${filename}".rar "${tempFolderToRar}"
done

# Optionnaly, delete temp directory if different from target
if [ "${TempDirectory}" != "${TargetDirectory}" ]
    then
    rm -r "${TempDirectory}"
fi
```

Save this to a file with no extension, be sure to set the good paths in the first variables and it should work fine running it in terminal.app

### Conclusion

Well, It worked for me.

Note: this script is not perfect. Maybe there's a better way, but it works ;) that was one of my first shell script, would probably be better with parameters, or go with python ;)

Hope it helps.

Comment: If every novice bash programmer would write code of this quality, the world of scripts would be a better place! Well done.

Comment: Thanks, that is my first bash script ever ^^. I Wrote alot of comments for learning purpose

Comment: `rm -r ${TempDirectory}`, `mkdir ${TempDirectory}`, and `mkdir ${TargetDirectory}` should also be double-quoted. You should probably use something like `mktemp -td` or `mkdir /tmp/$(uuidgen)` for creating the temporary directory. The files in the rar archives are extracted to `$PWD/$TempDirectory`.

Comment: I don't think you can save to `/bin` anymore, so you should use `/usr/local/bin` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simpler script like the one posted by GabLeRoux. `rar` can be downloaded from from http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in ~/Desktop/*.zip; do
    d=/tmp/$(uuidgen)
    unzip "$f" -d $d
    cd "$d"
    rm -rf __MACOSX
    ~/bin/rar a "${f%zip}rar" *
    rm -r "$d"
done
```

Comment: Err, there is a `cd ..` missing somewhere :-)

Comment: What do you mean? The glob expression at the start is `~/Desktop/*.zip` just for testing.

Comment: You cd into $d but where do you get out of the directory again?

Comment: The PWD at the end wouldn't matter unless the script does something after converting the archives. It could be kept by running the script in a subshell with `(  )` or with something like `oldpdw="$PWD"` ... `cd "$oldpwd"`.

Comment: Join me in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4519/room-for-patrix-and-lri to discuss further

Comment: Ok, Lri convinced me that it works that way...